# What is the difference between ios_base::sync_with_stdio(0); and ios::sync_with_stdio(0); in C++?

Tags: c++, difference

My mentors in CP recommended me to use ios_base::sync_with_stdio(0); since it increases the speed of program execution. While going through some videos on YouTube, I came across ios::sync_with_stdio(0); also.

So, What difference does adding or deleting **_base** make?

Which is better, ios_base::sync_with_stdio(0); or ios::sync_with_stdio(0);?

Kindly explain. Thanking you in advance.

Comment: Step through them with a debugger to find out their difference.

Comment: Don't use either unless you have a good reason to. Do you understand where this speed increase comes from and do you really need it? Same question to your mentor.

Comment: None is better. `ios::sync_with_stdio` is a static method inherited from `ios_base` and it is literally the same thing.

Comment: @Evg Thank you for responding, sir. I've some inkling regarding that. Using this, ios_base::sync_with_stdio(0); synchronization between C and C++ standard streams is disabled. So, C++ has its own buffer independent from C which makes things work faster. My mentors recommended this since I was repeatedly getting Time Limit Exceeding while participating in Codechef's Long Challenge.

Comment: @freakish May you please explain what is _static method_ ?

Comment: @BhavyaMalhotra `static` is a fundamental concept in C++, read this: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/static

Comment: Frankly, I don't understand it. Why do people start with participating in some moot contests before learning the language they're using? The majority of the so called competitive coding websites contain examples of really bad and unmaintainable code. Using those websites to learn the language is just a waste of time. From the practical point of view, the code clarity is much more important than speed that might come from `sync_with_stdio`-like tricks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> What is the difference between ios_base::sync_with_stdio(0); and ios::sync_with_stdio(0); in C++?

One takes 5 characters more `_base` to type.  There are no other differences.

The function is defined as a static public member function in `ios_base` class. `ios` is really `typedef basic_ios<char> ios;` and `basic_ios` inherits from `ios_base`. As so, `ios_base::sync_with_stdio` is inherited from `ios_base` to `basic_ios<char>` and to `ios`. It's the same function. The same way you can `std::wios::sync_with_stdio` or `std::basic_ios<wchar_t>::sync_with_stdio` etc.

For more information see [cppreference io](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io), [cppreference static members](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/static), [cppreference sync_with_stdio](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/ios_base/sync_with_stdio), [cppreference derived classes](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/derived_class) and I always propose to read a good C++ introduction book.

> Which is better, ios_base::sync_with_stdio(0); or ios::sync_with_stdio(0);?

They are equal.

Comment: Thank you! I'm not quite familiar with these classes and functions you mentioned but got the crux of your answer. Probably, in further studies as well, this detailed answer will help me understand the internal mechanisms of programming better. Thanks again!